# Configure VueJS pages (multiple pages in vue.config.js) MPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, multi-page-application

I'm making a **MPA**, using an *admin* side and a *client* side.

I need to configure the vue.config.js to do that.
I found in the documentation that I need to make an object of every page.
(https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages)
These are the mines:

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    admin: {
      entry: 'src/Admin/main.js',
      template: 'public/admin.html',
      filename: 'admin.html',
      title: 'Admin Page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'admin']
    },
    index: {
      entry: 'src/Client/main.js',
      template: 'public/client.html',
      filename: 'client.html',
      title: 'Client Page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'client']
    },
  },
}
```

The ***problem*** of that configuration is that **Vue takes the "index" as a subpage**.

I want to access the pages at: localhost:8080/. But it only loads client/main.js accessing to localhost:8080/index/

How should I configure the vue.config.js to use one main.js for *localhost:8080/* and a diferent one for *localhost:8080/admin/*

What is the "title" and "chucks" for? I only copy it from the official docs.

Comment: The problem is you're using the same `filename` for both pages. Don't do that

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it. But now my problem is different. I can´t access to the sites of the root localhost:8080/. It need to use the path localhost:8080/index

Comment: Had the same issue, but could not find a solution, so I just used the 'index' page as the site root.

Answer (score -1):

> Thanks! I fixed it. But now my problem is different. I can´t access to
>   the sites of the root localhost:8080/. It need to use the path
>   localhost:8080/index

I had the same issue with the regular app not being served at the root and couldn't find anything in the docs. When I renamed the `index` page key to some other name though (`client` in the case below), the main app was available at the root: `localhost:port/`

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    client: {
      entry: 'src/Client/main.js',
      template: 'public/client.html',
      filename: 'client.html',
      title: 'Client Page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'client']
    },
    admin: {
      entry: 'src/Admin/main.js',
      template: 'public/admin.html',
      filename: 'admin.html',
      title: 'Admin Page',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'admin']
    }
  }
}
```